# Check time after a mousebuttondown before the mousebuttonup

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, wpf-controls, mouseevent

I think that must be only a little problem, but I can't get a clear thought on that. Someone an idea?

I have some borders on a canvas (filled with images) and i want to click the border (i do this with the OnMouseLeftButtonDown) where the border gets red (so the user knows for sure which object he had clicked) and then, after 1 or 2 seconds, when the mousebutton is still pushed down, a drag'n'drop should start.

At first I had the borders inside buttons, but the clickevent seems to conflict with the dragevent. So I got rid of the buttons and did everything inside the borders directly, which works well also. But how can I start the drag after the mousebuttondown and stop it when the mousebuttonup happens before the time runs out.

Someone an idea for a clean solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _source = sender as Border;
    Mouse.Capture(_source);
}

private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _source = null;
    Mouse.Capture(null);
}
```

and in event OnMouseMove you can modify border margins depends on mouse position but after checking if _source is type of Border.

```
var position = e.GetPosition(Canvas);
```

EDIT:
For that time you can add property Stopwatch _watch, and inside OnMouseLeftButtonDown event handler you can do it:

```
_watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

in OnMouseLeftButtonUp:

```
_watch.Stop();
```

and in OnMouseMove before your code:

```
while (_watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 2000 && _watch.IsRunning)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: ok, I had to adjust it a little bit, but I didn't knew the Stopwatch-object till now. Thanks for that.