# How to change the location of wpf grid at run time?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have created a WPF Grid. That grid contains Textbox and Button controls.Here i want to relocate the grid at run time .How its possible please answer this if you know.Like a movable window.

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to relocate after mouse events or in code after some different event? If second you can change grid margins in event/method where you want to do it and call UpdateLayout() method after it. If first here is my answer for similar question:

[Check time after a mousebuttondown before the mousebuttonup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587046/check-time-after-a-mousebuttondown-before-the-mousebuttonup/31587520#31587520)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on stackoveflow

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Blue" 
Width="100" Height="100" 
MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp">
<Grid.RenderTransform>
<TranslateTransform x:Name="tt"/>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

Place it in a window

```
<Window x:Name="window" ...>
<Grid x:Name="grid"...
```

And code:

```
Point m_start;
Vector m_startOffset;

private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
m_start = e.GetPosition(window);
m_startOffset = new Vector(tt.X, tt.Y);
grid.CaptureMouse();
}

private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
if (grid.IsMouseCaptured)
{
    Vector offset = Point.Subtract(e.GetPosition(window), m_start);

    tt.X = m_startOffset.X + offset.X;
    tt.Y = m_startOffset.Y + offset.Y;
}
}

private void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
grid.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
```